# View which was removed and added to another layout looses content

Tags: java, android, layout, view

I am trying to remove a view from a RelativeLayout and adding it to another relativeLayout which is a child of the first one:

```
    root.removeView(iv);     // root is the main RelativeLayout
    RelativeLayout Box = rootChild   //rootChild is a RelativeLayout inside root
    Box.addView(iv);
```

The problem is that when the view is added to Box, it looses all of its content and only the View's background can be seen.

How can I add the view to the layout without loosing the content?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding it first and remove it afterwards?

@mod: this is meant as a comment but i cant add this as such. Please put this where it belongs. Thanks!

Comment: That throws a logcat error and it says that the View already has a parent.

Comment: Well yeah, that what it should do...-.- I tried it with my own code. Problem is, that I can't replicate the bug - it works fine here.

Comment: If it helps, rootchild and iv were added programatically